# Find dead code in Golang monorepo

Tags: go, refactoring

My team has all our Golang code in a monorepo.

- Various package subdirectories with library code.
- Binaries/services/tools under `cmd`

We've had it for a while and are doing some cleanup. Are there any tools or techniques that can find functions not used by the binaries under `cmd`?

I know `go vet` can find private functions that are unused in a package. However I suspect we also have exported library functions that aren't used either.

Comment: @JimB Appreciate the ideas, thank you. Unfortunately we have spotty code coverage. The `guru` tool could be useful.

Comment: please consider accepting this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77651165/9208887. Its most up to date.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**UPD 2020:**  The `unused` tool has been incorporated into `staticcheck`.
Unfortunately, `v0.0.1-2020.1.4` will probably be the last to support this
feature.  Dominik [explains](//github.com/dominikh/go-tools/commit/5cfc85b7) that it is because the check consumes a lot of
resources and is hard to get right.

To get that version:

```sh
env GO111MODULE=on go get honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@v0.0.1-2020.1.4
```

To use it:

```sh
$ staticcheck --unused.whole-program=true -- ./...
./internal/pkg/a.go:5:6: type A is unused (U1001)
```

Original answer below.

---

Dominik Honnef's [`unused`](//github.com/dominikh/go-tools) tool might be what you're looking for:

> Optionally via the -exported flag, unused can analyse all arguments as a
> single program and report unused exported identifiers. This can be useful for
> checking "internal" packages, or large software projects that do not export
> an API to the public, but use exported methods between components.

Comment: It seems like `unused` doesn't exist anymore as a standalone tool and was replaced by `staticcheck`. I don't seem to be able to do this with `staticcheck`, do you know how?

Comment: thank you! `$ go run honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck --unused.whole-program=true -- ./...` worked well for me!

Comment: https://staticcheck.io/changes/2020.2/#unused-whole-program  Beginning with Staticcheck 2020.2, there is no longer a whole-program mode in `staticcheck`

Comment: staticcheck ./...

Comment: This is how you use it now: `staticcheck -checks U1000 ./...`

Answer (score 6):

Try running `go build -gcflags -live`. This passes the `-live` flag to the compiler (`go tool compile`), instructing it to output debugging messages about liveness analysis. Unfortunately, it only prints when it's found live code, not dead code, but you could in theory look to see what *doesn't* show up in the output.

Here's an example from compiling the following program stored in `dead.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    if true {
        fmt.Println(true)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(false)
    }
}
```

Output of `go build -gcflags -live`:

```
# _/tmp/dead
./dead.go:7: live at call to convT2E: autotmp_5
./dead.go:7: live at call to Println: autotmp_5
```

If I'm reading this correctly, the second line states that the implicit call to `convT2E` (which converts non-interface types to interface types, since `fmt.Println` takes arguments of type `interface{}`) is live, and the third line states that the call to `fmt.Println` is live. Note that it *doesn't* say that the `fmt.Println(false)` call is live, so we can deduce that it must be dead.

I know that's not a perfect answer, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

https://go.dev/blog/deadcode - recently released by the Go team can be used for this purpose

```
$ go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/deadcode@latest
$ deadcode -help
The deadcode command reports unreachable functions in Go programs.

Usage: deadcode [flags] package...
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit dirty, but it works for me.
I had a lot of structs which I did not want to test manually, so I wrote a script that renames the struct then runs all the tests (ci/test.sh) and renames it back if any test failed:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

git grep 'struct {' | grep type | while read line; do
  file=$(echo $line | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')
  struct=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}') 

  sed "s/$struct struct/_$struct struct/g" -i $file

  echo "testing for struct $struct changed in file $file"

  if ! ./ci/test.sh; then
    sed "s/_$struct struct/$struct struct/g" -i $file
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an open source solution, but it works.

If you guys are using [Goland](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/), you should consider using its [code-inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/code-inspections-in-go.html) feature, includes useful features:

- Reports unused constant
- Reports unused exported functions
- Reports unused exported types in the main package and in tests
- Reports unused unexported functions
- Reports global variables that are defined but are never used in code
- Reports unused function parameters
- Reports unused types

(It looks like the implementation of this feature is black box, jetbrains does not open source this feature)

Go-related detection tools seem to place more emphasis on accuracy, and they want to do their best to minimize error reporting. And using [Goland](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/)'s [code-inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/code-inspections-in-go.html) feature may require more self-judgment. :)

Interests: Paid users only, not working for Jetbrains, simply think this feature works well.

Comment: To manually run an inspection: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-inspections.html#run-inspections-manually

Answer (score 1):

So staticcheck doesn't run full program analysis any more unfortunately as its by far the best solution.

There is also https://github.com/bep/punused, which works but gives a lot of false positives like for example everything that uses reflection and interfaces. But it is currently the only tool I know that can still run full program analysis

Answer (score 0):

A reliable but inelegant method I've used is to rename or comment out functions you suspect might not be used and then recompile everything -- no errors means you didn't need them.

If they are needed, it shows you where these functions are called so it's good for getting familiar with a code base and seeing how things connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Staticcheck for this: https://staticcheck.io/

```
$ staticcheck -checks U1000 ./...
cmd/something.go:202:6: func fmtIntegerOrNull is unused (U1000)
cmd/config.go:46:6: func must is unused (U1000)
server/logger.go:14:5: var echoContextLogger is unused (U1000)
internal/api/http.go:19:2: field status is unused (U1000)
internal/api/http.go:21:2: field message is unused (U1000)
...
```